# Parsing Datetime as yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss

Tags: c#, linq, date, datetime

My `stringQuery` returns datetime value in the following format `08/05/2015 15:21:40`,  but I would like to extract the parse datetime in following format - `yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss` as `datetime` type.

I have tried the following code variations but the my `convert` variable keeps returning the datetime as `08/05/2015 15:21:40`, instead of **`2015-05-08 15:21:40`**

```
   var stringQuery = (from p in db.Database_CRE_Events
                    select new Loan()
                    {
                        cDate = p.LastUpdated

                    }).FirstOrDefault();

        if (stringQuery != null && stringQuery.cDate.HasValue)
       {               
           var ott = stringQuery.cDate.Value;
           tt = ott.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss zzz");
           //format = dtt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
           //convert = DateTime.ParseExact(inp, "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss", provider);

       }
        convert = DateTime.ParseExact(tt, "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss zzz", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Please advice further, as to where I may be going wrong?
Many thanks

Comment: what's the type on the `tt` object?

Comment: its `string tt = "";`

Comment: 08/05/2015 15:21:40, and 2015-05-08 15:21:40 are equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

> but the my convert variable keeps returning the datetime as 08/05/2015
>   15:21:40, instead of 2015-05-08 15:21:40

`convert` is of type `DateTime`. **It is irrespective of the format.** What you are seeing is probably the debugger showing you the date in specific format.

`DateTime` is stored as just a number *(ticks)*, format is for presentation purpose.

I am not even sure why are you trying convert a `DateTime` object to string *first*, and then parsing it back to `DateTime`, simply use the original `DateTime` object and use string format wherever you need to display it.

Comment: How else can I format the code without converting it into string? Also, I require the datetime to be displayed as `2015-05-08 15:21:40` format, only because the `convert` dateTime type is further used in another query which only takes into account datetime types.

Comment: apology if my explanation is not clear enough. Thank you for your reply and help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want your DateTime to be string at the end of format "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss":

```
var myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss";

tt = "08/05/2015 15:21:40"
var dbFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss";

var result = DateTime.ParseExact(tt, format , null);
var formattedResult = result.ToString(myFormat);
```

> but I would like to extract the parse datetime in following format - yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss as datetime type.

08/05/2015 15:21:40 and 2015-05-08 15:21:40 are the same. It doesn't make sense to have differing formats for DateTime types unless you're wanting to display it somewhere as a string, where formatting matters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  How can I make the `result` variable as `DateTime` type?

Comment: It is `DateTime` type already.  If you want to explicitly make it `DateTime`, declare it as `DateTime` instead of `var`.  But it is the same either way.

Comment: Yes, I aware of this fact. However, i need to pass the datetime as `2015-05-08 15:21:40` to another linq query `where clause`, where the query only recognises datetime values such as '2015-05-08 15:21:40' instead of `08/05/2015 15:21:40`.

Comment: Seems to me like your LINQ query uses string for comparison instead of DateTime if formatting is an issue. Post your LINQ query too.